# "Give me what you wish".. here what part of speech is "what"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Why is *what* is a certain type of part of speech as used here?

Comment: The embedded question clause _what you wish_ begins with the _Wh_-word _what_; it is the object of _wish_, but moved to the beginning by question formation. You can call it any part of speech you like - pronoun and complementizer are common choices.

Comment: @John Lawler Pronouns of the Season.

Comment: Complementizer is not a part of speech but a function. "What you wish" is not an embedded question but a noun phrase in a fused relative construction where "what" is a pronoun. This kind of fused relative is called the 'free choice' construction because it's for you to decide what you wish to give me. Note, though, that "whatever" would be the usual pronoun.  The meaning is "Give me anything that you wish (to give me)"

Answer (score 1):

In a comment BillJ wrote:

> Complementizer is not a part of speech but a function. "What you wish" is not an embedded question but a noun phrase in a fused relative construction where "what" is a pronoun. This kind of fused relative is called the 'free choice' construction because it's for you to decide what you wish to give me. Note, though, that "whatever" would be the usual pronoun.  The meaning is "Give me anything that you wish (to give me)"

Answer (score 0):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> The embedded question clause *what you wish* begins with the *Wh*-word *what*; it is the object of *wish*, but moved to the beginning by question formation. You can call it any part of speech you like - pronoun and complementizer are common choices.

Comment: @John Lawler Could you possibly give an estimate of what percentage of people who would pronounce on the issue would choose 'pronoun' and how many 'complementizer', please, John?